# Compute and plot the normalised proportion (%) of a categorical variable as a function of another categorical variable (or two) + 95% CI

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I would like to plot the normalised proportion (i.e., percentage) of the different values of a categorical variable as a function of the values of two other categorical variables in a data frame.

I am using a data frame where I have three columns: XPEvidence, XPIntention and 'subject label'. XPEvidence can take two categorical values: weak or strong, the XPIntention can take two categorical values: Defense or Prosecution and the variable subject label can take four different values.

Is there a way to plot the normalised proportion of categorical values according to the values of the two other variables?

I found the count.plot of the seaborn library to show the frequency - but it shows a simple count of the different values and not the % (which is a more useful information).

`sns.factorplot(x = 'XPObjective', hue="subject label", col="XPEvidence",
                   col_order = ['weak', 'Strong'], data=dfvp, kind="count")`

I found the percentage of subject label values according to the two XP variables using the groupby and the count function + normalize:
`dfgrouped_XP['subject label'].value_counts(normalize=True)`

Is there a way to directly plot these percentages?

Final question: Is there a way to automatically compute and add error bars showing the 95% confidence intervals in the plot?
Thank you VERY much for your help.
Marie

Comment: I have searched for this too - but sorry did not find... I would be super interested in knowing how to do that - displaying percentages is more informative than displaying counts... Thanks for the question!

Comment: ha ha! I just  realised I answered 'I don't know' to myown question... Too bad! I thought there was someone else like me out there! :/